# r - Plotting function curves using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve

Using R base graphics, I have been able to draw a plot with four curves computed from simple functions with this script:

```
I0 <- log(1)
I1 <- log(1/2)
b <- .1
d <- .01
d1 <- .014

curve(exp(I0 - b * x), 0, 50, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
curve(exp(d * x) - 1, 0, 50, add = TRUE, col = "orange", lwd = 2)
curve(exp(I1 - b * x), 0, 50, add = TRUE, lty = 2, col = "green", lwd = 2)
curve(exp(d1 * x) - 1, 0, 50, add = TRUE, lty = 2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: Plot using base graphics]

But when attempting to reproduce the same plot using ggplot2 and the script below, I got something weird:

```
library(ggplot2)

I0 <- log(1)
I1 <- log(1/2)
b <- .1
d <- .01
d1 <- .014

base <- ggplot() + xlim(0, 50) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(I0 - b * x), colour = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(d * x), colour = "orange") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(I1 - b * x), color = "green") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(d1 * x), color = "red")

plot(base)
```

[image: Plot using ggplot]

Also, how could I change the line width (presumably using geom_line())?

I understand that this is sort of a dumb question, but could someone out there give me some hints?

Comment: Using `curve`is obviously more intuitive. Also, you don't have to edit out ugly tiles before submitting to a journal.

Comment: Hi, @jay,sf! I do agree that curve() is more intuitive, but as far as I know, there is no such function in ggplot. I don't know what you mean by "ugly tiles", but ggplot graphs are much prettier than those generated by R base graphics (it is the very reason for the existence of ggplot, anyway).

Comment: More flashier maybe, it's subjective anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions don't match is why: missing `- 1` on the orange and red lines. `linewidth` will control the line width.

```
ggplot() + xlim(0, 50) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(I0 - b * x), colour = "blue", linewidth = 0.1) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(d * x) - 1, colour = "orange", linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(I1 - b * x), color = "green") +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) exp(d1 * x) - 1, color = "red")
```

[image]

or with `+ ggthemes::theme_base()`

[image]